# Click on <li>, fadeOut(#div1), fadeIn related index div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and my way of learning is by following tutorials and tweak them afterwards.
I am making a quiz from two tutorials combined where I have the following html code

```
<div class="questionContainer 1 hide">
        <ul class="answers img-hover">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul> 
        <div class="btnContainer">
            <div class="next">
                <a class="btnNext" href="#"><img class="btnNext" src="img/Knap.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="questionContainer 2 hide">
        <ul class="answers img-hover">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul> 
        <div class="btnContainer">
            <div class="prev">
                <a class="btnPrev" href="#">Previous</a>
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <a class="btnNext" href="#"><img class="btnNext" src="img/Knap.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="progressKeeper">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

There are a total of 9 questions and progress indicator dots.
jQuery is being used to handle the question divs with `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` and with "next" and "previous" buttons.

```
$('.btnNext').click(function(){

                var tempCheck = $(this).parents('.questionContainer').find('input[type=radio]:checked');
            if (tempCheck.length == 0) {
                 notice.fadeIn(300);return false;
            }
                 notice.hide();
            $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(500);


                $('#progressKeeper ul li a.step.green').last().parent().next('li').find('a').addClass('green');

            });
                 return false;
        });         


        $('.btnPrev').click(function(){
                notice.hide();
            $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).prev().fadeIn(500);
                $('#progressKeeper ul li a.step.green').last().parent().last('li').find('a').removeClass('green');
            });
                 return false;
        });
```

What I am trying to achieve is when a user click on a progress indicator, fade out current questionContainer div and fade in the relative questionContainer. So if you are at the 8th question and click on progress indicator 1, fade out current div and fade in div no. 1.

How can I achieve this?

P.S. I have left irrelevant code so it might not make 100% sense the above code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is an ideal candidate for a JSFiddle or inline snippet. You can also introduce yourself to the `TidyUp` button on JSFiddle to format your code to be more readable :)

Comment: I am new to this forum and JSFiddle. I'll try to update the post with you suggestions. Sounds like a good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it up like this:

```
<div class="questionContainer step0 active"></div>
<div class="questionContainer step1"></div>
<div class="questionContainer step2"></div>
<div class="questionContainer step3"></div>


<div id="progressKeeper">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

script:

```
$(".step").click(function(){
  index = $(this).parent().index();

  //hide active step
  $(".questionContainer.active").fadeOut(500, function(){
       //remove active class 
       $(this).removeClass('active');

       //show index and add active class
       $(".questionContainer.step"+index).fadeIn();
       $(".questionContainer.step"+index).addClass('active');
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yak06am1/1/

Comment: OP said "So if you are at the 8th question and click on progress indicator 1, fade out current div and fade in div no. 1." but this scenario doesnt work in the fiddle (I understand there is no div 8, but div 1 doesnt display when i'm on the supposed div 8)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but updated the fiddle so there can be no confusion about the div numbers. <http://jsfiddle.net/yak06am1/1/> also removed the list style type. When i click on a indicator the associated div appears and the old one fades out...

Comment: Jeroen, you solution works like a charm, I have another question though. I am adding a class of `.green` to the anchor tag to change the background image from a grey to a green dot. I'd like to only make your solution to work when you click on one of the green dots and not the grey ones, since you're not there yet. I tried to change your code to `$(".step.green").click(function(e)` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I made a JSFiddle to show you what I've got [http://jsfiddle.net/umutucler/rgyhhd9q/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/umutucler/rgyhhd9q/2/). As it is now, I'd like to disable the grey squares to not be clickable, only the green ones. I'd also like to, when you are at question 5 and click on the 3rd progress indicator, to remove the .green class from the ones coming after the clicked indicator and keep it on the clicked one and those before. I've tried for hours now and have not succeded. Can you help with that also?